# Using the existing glance screen of WatchOS 2 as snapshot of the watch app for WatchOS 3

Tags: ios, snapshot, watchos-3, wkrefreshbackgroundtask

I have an Apple WatchOS2 app which I need to upgrade it to WatchOS 3. As there is no glance screen on WatchOS 3 anymore I'm not sure how to use the current glance screen to create automatic snapshot by calling scheduleSnapshotRefresh method in WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask. Can I migrate the whole project from WatchOS 2 target to a WatchOS 3 target and apply changes to make it compatible with WatchOS 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/WatchBackgroundRefresh/Introduction/Intro.html

This updates the view on awake.

You can also try updating the snap shot view when you receive a refresh task (WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask).

https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wksnapshotrefreshbackgroundtask

Greg

Comment: Thanks Greg, it was very useful! one more question do you also know should I create a separate target for WatchOS 3 project or I still can keep working with the existing WatchOS2 and add new features for WatchOS 3 there? while I need to run the app on both WatchOS 2 and WatchOS 3 devices.

Comment: You can target WatchOS 2 and add WatchOS 3 features but you will need to check the OS when ever you use a watchOS 3 feature. Personally I think most users will update so I would build an OS 3 version and 2 version and when 3 is released then release your OS3 app but have it require v3 as a minimum. That way you don't have to support multiple OS versions. But I'm lazy.

Comment: Thanks again Greg! It's a good idea though users might be lazy to upgrade to WatchOS 3 as well and creating a separate build for OS 3 requires too much work for me and I'm lazy to do that :)